# jquery .change not working in IE7

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-selectors

I have a form with `id="new"`

I have several text inputs and a select drop down on it.

I'm using the jquery code:

```
$('form#new').change(function(){
    alert('this code works');
});
```

But the `.change()` function does not work in IE7, however it does work in all other browsers including IE9

Is this a jQuery bug or do I have my coding wrong here some how?

What might be an alternative method of doing this?

the actual thing I'm trying to accomplish here is using

```
$(this).serialize();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably be safer binding to the form inputs' onchange events:

```
$('#new :input').change(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().serialize());
});
```

Comment: thank you sir. That worked perfectly. You are a scholar and a gentleman.

Comment: So I guess the issue was just that IE7 was having an issue pointing to the whole form changing, rather then just each individual element.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is specifically, but I ran into this a while back with an ajax form which submits and fetches results each time an input changes (including select fields), and rather than get to the bottom of why IE7 didn't like it, I applied that workaround and forgot about it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try

```
$('form#new').children().change(function(){
    alert('this code works');
});
```